# How to Remove Shopping cart from the footer on checkout page?

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

[image]

This is the code that I am added in checkout.xml

```
 <checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
    <label>One Page Checkout</label>
    <!-- Mage_Checkout -->

    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="right">
        <action method="unsetChildren"></action>
        <block type="checkout/onepage_review_info" name="checkout_review_sidebar" output="toHtml" before="-" template="checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/onepage/review/totals.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.before" as="items_before" translate="label">
                <label>Items Before</label>
            </block>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after" as="items_after" translate="label">
                <label>Items After</label>
            </block>
            <!-- <block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.agreements" as="agreements" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"/>
        This block is only for information; we don't want the "Place Order" button showing.
            <block type="core/template" name="checkout.onepage.review.button" as="button" template="checkout/onepage/review/button.phtml"/>
        -->
        </block>
     </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

Can any one pls help me to remove from the footer section

Comment: so why you added this code in checkout

Comment: I want to show the summary of the cart in the right sidebar, that's why  I added the code

Comment: But your page is 1column  layout

Comment: check answer and let me know

Comment: i have already change to 2columns-right

Comment: by looking  this looks like  1 column layout please cross check

Comment: check the xml code in question

Comment: i added complete xml code

Comment: so Now its working ???

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below code inside the block name called **checkout.progress.wrapper**

```
<block type="checkout/onepage_review_info" name="checkout_review_sidebar"  template="checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml">
                        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
                    <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/onepage/review/totals.phtml"/>
                    <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.before" as="items_before" translate="label">
                        <label>Items Before</label>
                    </block>
                    <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after" as="items_after" translate="label">
                        <label>Items After</label>
                    </block>
                    </block>
```

Answer (score 0):

first change the your layout to `2columns-right` and then set cart detail in right

```
<checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
<reference name="right">
            <action method="unsetChildren"></action>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_review_info" name="checkout_review_sidebar" output="toHtml" before="-" template="checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/onepage/review/totals.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.before" as="items_before" translate="label">
                    <label>Items Before</label>
                </block>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after" as="items_after" translate="label">
                    <label>Items After</label>
                </block>
  </reference>
  <reference name="footer">
        <remove name="checkout_review_sidebar">
  <reference>   
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

Comment: i have already change to 2columns-right

Comment: this is not working

Comment: Path of this file ??

Comment: path : /app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/checkout.xml

Comment: @prashanth check updated answer

Comment: while adding the above the code cart and checkout is working

Comment: @prashanth any other problem ??

Comment: is there any other way show the summary of the cart in the sidebar

Comment: why Is it not showing right now ??

Comment: after adding the reference footer the cart and checkout is not showing

Comment: @prashanth so your is solved ??

Comment: not yet solved can you give some solution to this

Comment: it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Override 2columns-right.phtml and renove the following code.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
```

Comment: can you explain in details

Comment: Please, search on google to find how can i override template in mageto 1.x